# Unable to scan the elements into array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am beginner in Java. I wrote a few lines of code, and it is showing error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Issue {
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    int ID[]=new int[n];
    String [] Name=new String[n];
    public void get()
    {

        int ID[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter " + (i+1) + "st Employe ID :");
            ID[i] = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Employe Name:");
            Name[i]=scan.nextLine();

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Issue obj=new Issue();
        System.out.println("Enter no.of Employes:");
        obj.n=scan.nextInt();
        obj.get();

    }
}
```

Comment: use `next()` instead of `nextLine()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: yes @Nisarg that works but for string we should use nextLine() right?. what the issue with nextLine() in my code

Answer (score 0):

At the time you have created the object of class Issue, the value of n was 0 and so you have created the arrays of ID and Name with size 0. Now after you have taken the input from user, you have only set n to the user input but the ID[] and Name[] arrays still have size 0. So inside the get method you are accessing out of box indexes in the 0-size arrays.

Here is the corrected code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Issue {
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    int ID[];
    String [] Name;
    public void get()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter " + (i+1) + "st Employe ID :");
            ID[i] = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Employe Name:");
            Name[i]=scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Issue obj=new Issue();
        System.out.println("Enter no.of Employes:");
        obj.n=scan.nextInt();
        obj.Name =new String[n];
        obj.ID = new int[n];
        obj.get();

    }
}
```

In above code I have only made correction for ArrayIndexOutOfBound. However your code can be improved by following good programming practices like these:

1. Follow the naming conventions of methods and variables.
2. Make the non-final member objects of a class private and use getters and setters.
3. Follow separation of concern rule.
4. Use BufferedReader instead of Scanner for faster performance.

Comment: iam unable understand but ur code is works . I updated n value with user input right then why ID[] and Name[] has 0 index.

Comment: @barrekonda Thats because you only updated the value of n from 0 to possibly some positive integer. However, ID and Name array were initialised earlier effectively like this:
 `int ID[] = new int[0]`
`String Name[] = new String[0]`
However you havent made the new arrays according to the new value of n.
If you got it and if the code works, kindly accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky, because although you set with `obj.n=scan.nextInt();` a number to `n`, the array's size remains `0` since it has been initialized with the dafult `n` value 0.

The line:

```
obj.n=scan.nextInt();
```

Doesn't assure the reallocation of memory for the arrays `ID` and `Name`. I suggest you to avoid public variables and use the constructor for the total number encapsulation.

```
public static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

private final int n;
private final int ID[];
private final String[] Name;

public Main(int number) {
    this.n = number;
    this.ID = new int[n];
    this.Name = new String[n];
}

public void get() {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter " + (i+1) + "st Employe ID :");
        ID[i] = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Employe Name:");
        Name[i] = scan.nextLine();

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter no.of Employes:");
    Main obj = new Main(scan.nextInt());
    obj.get();
}
```

Moreover, you have to call `scan.nextLine();` to consume the line itself, because [`Scanner::nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) doesn't terminate the line the same [`Scanner::nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) does.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>
> Occurs when you attempt to get element at an index greater than size of the
>   array.

For Example,

you have an array **A** of size 10 and you are accessing **A[10]** then you will get exception because

- Array size is 10 so valid indexes are 0-9 to access array element
- A[10] means accessing (10+1)th element that is greater than array size(10)

In your case you have initialized arrays **ID** and **Name** at time when variable **n** is having value 0. To resolve this error you should **initialize these arrays after variable n is initialized**.